# Huawei push kit : SendException: device not in device group

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I have set up PushKit in my app and **I want to send upstream message**. On a device it fails with the following exception:

```
com.huawei.hms.push.SendException: device not in device group
    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.b(HmsMessageService.java:299)
    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:190)
    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:39)
    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService$a.handleMessage(HmsMessageService.java:162)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

- Length of message: 616
- Token gets generated

What is the meaning of this error?

Checking the [**docs** about this error](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/push-ErrorEnum4) , you can see this:

> ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_IN_GROUP
>
> Constant value: 907122057
>
> The device is not in the device group.

But no further details.

Comment: Can you share your code about upstream message?

Comment: Please provide the Sending Upstream Message part of your code. :)

Comment: Thanks to both you guys. Issue was because of passing wrong `builder` arg when creating `RemoteMessage. I added the description in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case there was a mistake passing **`"push.hcm.upstream"`** to the `RemoteMessage.Builder` argeument.

Code before:

```kotlin
val builder = RemoteMessage.Builder("SOMETHING_WRONG")
```

Code that is correct:

```kotlin
val builder = RemoteMessage.Builder("push.hcm.upstream")
```

Despite surprisingly success of sending message on a device, with this correction made, the uplinks will be sent with no issues.